# Как заполнить массив словами определенной длины?

Tags: c++, строки, динамические-массивы, char

Вот текст задачи:
Реализовать метод, возвращающий массив слов длины N из заданной строки (знаки
препинания, расположенные в начале и в конце слов, не учитывать). Если строка не
содержит слов длины N, оставить результирующий массив пустым.

Итак, нужно

1. Пробежаться по введенной строке и узнать количество слов (я это сделал)
2. Создать массив для слов длины N (тоже сделано)
3. Вбить в этот массив слова длины N (тут уже возникли затруднения)

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
         SetConsoleCP(1251);
         SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int slovo = 0, count = 0, word_l;

    char s[80];

    cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
    cin.get(s, 80);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Введите размер слов, которые вы хотите вывести: ";
    cin >> word_l;
    cout << endl;

    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] == ' ' && s[i] != '\0' && s[i] != ',' && s[i] != '.' && s[i] != '!' && s[i] != '?' && s[i] != ':' && s[i] != ';') {
        i++;
    }


    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] != ' ' && slovo == 0 && s[i] != ',' && s[i] != '.' && s[i] != '!' && s[i] != '?' && s[i] != ':' && s[i] != ';') {
            slovo = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if (s[i] == ' ') {
            slovo = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Всего слов в строке " << count << endl;

    char* arr = new char[i]();


    delete[] arr;

    return 0;

      }
   ```

P.S. еще нужно игнорировать пробелы и всякие знаки препинания, как вы могли понять по коду

Comment: P.S. еще нужно игнорировать пробелы и всякие знаки препинания, как вы могли понять по коду

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
int count = 0, word_l;

const int size_word = 20; //Максимальный размер слова
const int count_words = 10; //Максимальное кол-во слов
const int size_str = 80; //Максимальная длина строки
char s[size_str];
char words[count_words][size_word];

cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
cin.get(s, size_word);
cout << endl;

cout << "Введите размер слов, которые вы хотите вывести: ";
cin >> word_l;
cout << endl;


char* ps = s; //pointer s
char* pss = 0; //pointer start s - указатель на начало слова
int size = 0;
while (*ps != '\0') {
    //Пропускаем знаки препинания и пробелы
    while (*ps != '\0' && isDelimiter(*ps)) ++ps;

    //Подсчитываем длину найденного слова
    size = 0;
    pss = ps;
    while (*ps != '\0' && !isDelimiter(*ps)) {
        ++size;
        ++ps;
    }

    //Подсчитываем кол-во слов, длина которых = word_l и копируем в массив слов
    if (size == word_l) {
        strncpy_s(*(words + count), pss, word_l);
        ++count;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << words[i] << endl;
```

Функция isDelimiter (делает код намного понятней)

```
bool isDelimiter(char s) {
return s == ' ' || s == ',' || s == '.' || s == '!' ||
       s == '?' || s == ':' || s == ';';
}
```

Если вам не нравится, что массив `words` статический, то просто перед циклом `while` подсчитайте кол-во слов. Рекомендую при подсчете, так же считать и кол-во слов длинной равной `n`, чтобы потом инициализировать массив `words` получившиеся длинной.